# Run a Symfony 4 flex console command script during composer installation

Tags: symfony, console, composer-php

Before Flex, we could extend Sensio's DistributionBundle  [Composer/ScriptHandler.php](https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioDistributionBundle/blob/master/Composer/ScriptHandler.php) to hook into bin/console and run commands as part of composer's "post-update-cmd" .

Unfortunately Flex eliminates the ScriptHandler file.  What's the best approach with Flex?  I tried creating an Application instead of ScriptHandler and calling that from "post-update-cmd":

```
#!/usr/bin/env php

    <?php
    // application.php

    require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

    use Symfony\Component\Console\Application;
    use Mybundle\MyUpdateCommand;

    $application = new Application();

    // ... register commands
    $application->add(new MyUpdateCommand());
    $application->run();
```

But this throws an error "event returned with error code 127". Thanks!

Comment: You can create your own Composer plugin for this purpose, please refer Composer [documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/plugins.md#creating-a-plugin) on this topic. You can also [browse](https://packagist.org/?type=composer-plugin) Composer plugins to see if there is something that would help you to satisfy your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add the command to `auto-scripts` section of `composer.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "auto-scripts": {
        ...
        ...
        "name:of:my:command": "symfony-cmd"
    }
}
```

This will run the script on every `composer install`/`update`.